# Sending a post request to a webhook address for RASA

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest, webhooks, rasa

In summary, I am trying to send a post request to Rasa server engine hosted on a local engine using Javascript. Ultimately, I am trying to build a chabot UI that feeds and interacts with the Rasa server.

[This](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/your-own-website) documentation tells me to send the post request to a particular webhook address, but so far I have not been successful in getting a proper response. Communication with the rasa server works when I use Insomnia, so I'm guessing there is something wrong with my code at the moment. My code is as followed:

```
var message = { 
sender: "Bobby",
message: "Hello!"
};

let url = "http://localhost:5055/webhooks/rest/webhook";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.addEventListener('load', () => {alert("hello World");});
req.open('post', url, true); // (method, url, async)
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.send(JSON.stringify(message));
```

This is the snippet of code that I am using to send the request. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a post and example of custom chatbot UI here: https://forum.rasa.com/t/chatbot-widget-for-rasa-using-rest-channel/21500. Does this help?